# how to use batch_tensordot in theano like numpy.einsum

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, theano, numpy-einsum

I have a tensor3 with shape (3, 4, 5) and another tensor4 with shape (3, 4, 7, 5).
In numpy,

```
 result = np.einsum("ijk, ijmk->ijm", tensor3, tensor4)
 print result.shape 
 (3, 4, 7)
```

but in theano , how to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to transpose and reshape your tensor so that only the first dimension gets preserved. In that case it is quite simple, you just have to combine the first two dimensions:

```
x = tensor.tensor3()
y = tensor.tensor4()
i, j, m, k = y.shape

x_ = x.reshape((i * j, k))
y_ = y.reshape((i * j, m, k))
```

Then, you specify to `batched_tensordot` that you are going to sum axis 1 of `x_` with axis 2 of `y_`:

```
z_ = tensor.batched_tensordot(x_, y_, (1, 2))  # shape (i * j, m)
```

Finally, reshape `z_` to get the first two dimensions:

```
z = z_.reshape((i, j, m))
print(z.eval({x: np.zeros((3, 4, 5)), y: np.zeros((3, 4, 7, 5))}).shape)
# (3, 4, 7)
```

Comment: thank you very much@Pascal Lamblin. You have solved my problem.But I just wonder why I tried  tensor.batched_tensordot(x, y, (2, 3)) and got the shape (i, j, j, m) other than (i, j, i, j, m)???

Comment: With batched_tensordot, the first axis is preserved (iterated jointly), so the first shape is i. Then, k is eliminated (becaused it is summed over). The remaining dimensions are j for x, and (j, m) for y, which get concatenated.
So finally, the shape is (i,) + (j,) + (j, m), or (i, j, j, m).
tensordot(x, y, (2, 3)) (without the batch) would have given you (i, j, i, j, m)